# Creating an efficient datatype for looking up conversion factors by initial and resulting units C#

Tags: c#, winforms, recursion, types, nested-loops

I'm trying to create a windows form application that will convert units of measurements from one to the other.  My form features navigation buttons that I figured would make it user friendly.

When the user selects a category from the main menu it fills the category of measurement combobox and sets default unit of measurements into two other combo boxes.

These comboboxes allow the user to select which unit of measurement they want.  When they choose a category such as distance, it fills the initial and resulting unit of measurement comboboxes.

I therefore have ***already*** created a few `string[]` that contains each unit of measurement.

```
string[] distanceUnits = { "Inches", "Feet", "Centimeters", "Meters", "Kilometers", "Miles" };
string[] massUnits = { "Grams", "Kilograms", "Pounds", "Ounces" };
```

I also created a couple different `decimal[]` arrays filled with conversion factors that I have been looking up and editing for precision purposes since I will be doing unit testing. I'd like to easily be able to change the conversion factor or add new ones into the arrays.

For example,

```
decimal[] massConversionFactors =
{
    .001m,               // [0] Grams to KiloGrams
    .00220462m,          // [1] Grams to Pounds
    .035274m,            // [2] Grams to Ounces
    1000,                // [3] KiloGrams to Grams
    2.20462m,            // [4] KiloGrams to Pounds
    35.274m,             // [5] KiloGrams to Ounces
    453.592m,            // [6] Pounds to Grams
    .453592m,            // [7] Pounds to Kilograms
    16                   // [8] Pounds to Ounces
};
```

and

```
decimal[] distanceConversionFactors =
{
    .083333m,             // [0] Inches to Feet
    2.54m,                // [1] Inches to Centimeters
    .0254m,               // [2] Inches to Meters
    .0000254m,            // [3] Inches to Kilometers
    .0000157828282828m,   // [4] Inches to Miles
    12,                   // [5] Feet to Inches
    30.48m,               // [6] Feet to Centimetes
    .3048m,               // [7] Feet to Meters
    .0003048m,            // [8] Feet to Kilometers
    .000189394m,          // [9] Feet to Miles
    .3937009133858m,      // [10] Centimeters to Inches
    .03280840944882m,     // [11] Centimeters to Feet
    .01m,                 // [12] Centimeters to Meters
    .00001m,              // [13] Centimeters to Kilometers
    .0000062137m,         // [14] Centimeters to Miles
    39.3701m,             // [15] Meters to Inches
    3.28084m,             // [16] Meters to Feet
    100,                  // [17] Meters to Centimeters
    .001m,                // [18] Meters to Kilometers
    .000621371m,          // [19] Meters to Miles
    39370.1m,             // [20] Kilometers to Inches
    3280.84m,             // [21] Kilometers to Feet
    100000,               // [22] Kilometers to Centimeters
    1000,                 // [23] Kilometers to Meters
    .621371m,             // [24] Kilometers to Miles
    63360,                // [25] Miles to Inches
    5280,                 // [26] Miles to Feet
    160934,               // [27] Miles to Centimeters
    1609.34m,             // [28] Miles to Meters
    1.60934m              // [29] Miles to Kilometers
};
```

That way when the submission button is pressed I can do a calculation such as:

```
private void ConvertSubmissionButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //User's input value
    decimal input = decimal.Parse(UserInputTextBox.Text);
    string initialUnits = InitialUnitsComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
    string resultingUnits = ResultingUnitsComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString();

    //conversion of user input to result accepting initial and resulting
    decimal result =  input * ObjectWithTooManyMethods(initalUnits, resultingUnits);

    ResultingValueLabel.Text = (initialUnits);
    ResultingValueLabel.Show();
}
```

This works fine for now, but as I add more methods to the object I wonder if there is a way to consolidate the already created arrays.

The problem I'm having is that I am forced to hardcode every permutation of conversion in the

```
ObjectWithTooManyMethods(string, string);
```

What I'd really like to do is create a recursive loop that will go through the `distanceUnits[]` `massUnits[]` and other unit of measurement category arrays, and creates every possible permutation based on the category's appropriate conversionFactor arrays. 
This way I can add on units of measurements and their conversion factors without coding an entire new method in the future.

Is this possible?

This ideal loop would create a single datatype that contains this information and be able to retrieve the decimal value for the conversion factor for initial, and resulting units when the user clicks a submission button.

Such as:

```
DesiredDatatype<string,string,decimal> conversionFactors = new DesiredDatatype<string,string,decimal>()
{
    {initialUnits, resultingUnits, conversionFactor}
};

    private void ConvertSubmissionButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //User's input value
        decimal input = decimal.Parse(UserInputTextBox.Text);
        string initialUnits = InitialUnitsComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
        string resultingUnits = ResultingUnitsComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString();

        decimal result =  input * conversionFactors.get(initialUnits, resultingUnits);

        ResultingValueLabel.Text = (result);
        ResultingValueLabel.Show();
    }
```

Maybe I'm approaching this the wrong way, and/or have been coding too long today.. I have looked up information about tuples and dictionarys and they seem like they would ideal for this scenario but I have failed in creating a working datatype from looping through the information in these existing arrays.

Any advice is greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: are you familiar with the `.Zip` method.

Comment: No, I have not used the .Zip method before.

Comment: You want a dictionary, or even a `List<SomeClassWithThreeProperties>`

Comment: Maybe List<Tuple<string, string, decimal>>

Comment: I'm confused about why you would even take this approach.  For a UOM such as length, for example, you just need to pick a standard unit--meters, for example, and provide conversions TO that.  One calculation can get you your conversion to anything else, and one calculation can get you your conversion in the other direction.  Perhaps that would cause a loss of precision converting from...nanometers to light years, or something?  Genuinely curious.

Comment: I suppose I should have explained that I am making a Windows Form application with menu navigation buttons. I wanted to reuse the string[] units arrays for comboboxes that I have already created, was thinking it would be good practice for memory consumption (although for my needs it may not really be necessary). Also I was neglecting to simply use an object oriented methodology. I was curious from a datatype construction approach which datatype would be efficient. I will be doing a unit test to check the precision of the data retrieved from the process, so precision does matter.

Comment: @Jamin: You don't have to show the user the value calculated in the "standard" unit, but having it does reduce the number of conversions you have to write from O(N^2) to O(N).  Which is hugely helpful.

Comment: @BenVoigt I am not too well knowledge about space-time complexity but I know enough that I would like to say reaching O(N) is one of the objectives in solving this problem. Can you please clarify why not showing the user the value calculated will reduce the number of calculations?  I'm not sure what/which value you're referring to, but I'd like to know more about reducing the complexity.

Comment: @Jamin: Consider [this picture](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Mohd_Mohamad3/publication/258524366/figure/fig5/AS:214123473313799@1428062422160/Neural-network-with-one-hidden-layer-of-neurons.png) of a hidden layer in a neural network, because your unit conversion takes the same shape.  Consider if there are 20 possible input and output units.  The hidden layer has only one node.  Then there are 40 arrows (conversions), 20 from inputs to hidden, and 20 from hidden to outputs.  But if you eliminate the hidden layer and go directly, there are 400 conversions (all possible in-out pairs)

Comment: It is having the extra layer that improves the complexity.  Hiding the layer is done because the user doesn't care, but whether you show or hide it doesn't affect the complexity.  Of course, the conversions are trivially reversible, and conversion back to the same unit is trivial, so the actual number of conversion factors you need for 20 units would be 19 using the intermediate step, vs 190 going direct.

Comment: As per my answer below, I would suggest considering solving this problem with objects rather than data structures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't want to use objects, what about using enumerations and dictionaries? You can define an enumeration like this...

```
public enum MassUnit
{
    Grams,
    Kilograms,
    Ounces,
    Pounds
}
```

To convert enum values to and from strings you can...

```
var stringArrayOfEnumNames = Enum.GetNames(typeof(Mass));
var enumFromString = Enum.Parse(typeof(MassUnit), "Ounces");
```

Next you could use a dictionary for your conversion amounts. There's no need to have every combination of conversions, just convert to a standard unit (grams) then convert to the destination unit. This dictionary stores values to convert any mass unit to grams.

```
public static Dictionary<MassUnit, decimal> MassToGramsMap = new Dictionary<MassUnit, decimal>
{
    [MassUnit.Grams] = 1m,
    [MassUnit.Kilograms] = .001m,
    [MassUnit.Ounces] = .035274m,
    [MassUnit.Pounds] = .00220462m
};
```

Then a conversion would look like...

```
var value = 100m;   
var from = MassUnit.Pounds;
var to = MassUnit.Kilograms;
var convertedValue = value / MassToGramsMap[from] * MassToGramsMap[to];
```

Now if you wanted to add a new mass unit, you would add it to the `MassUnit` enumeration and add its conversion to `MassToGramsMap` dictionary and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

I think you would be better served by creating hard-coded functions inside a helper class for this. There is really no reason to place all these constant inside a dynamic array. That's going to be abstract, confusing and hard to keep track of. For example, your mass conversion class could look like this:

```
public static class MassConversion
{
    public static decimal GramsToKilograms(decimal grams) {
        return grams * .001;
    }
    public static decimal GramsToPounds(decimal grams) {
        return grams * .00220462;
    }
    public static decimal GramsToOunces(decimal grams) {
        return grams * .035274;
    }
    public static decimal KilogramsToGrams(decimal kilograms) {
        return kilograms* 1000;
    }
    //...
};
```

Then, to use it:

```
var grams = 4267;
var kilos = MassConversion.GramsToKilograms(grams);
```

This also has the benefit of being self-documenting.

Comment: Thank you for solution.  After reading this I have edited my question to better reflect the problem I am having.  Although I could make an object that converts these units, I'm looking for a solution that creates a datatype (through looping) to store the conversionFactors so I don't have to hard code a function each time I add a conversion.  Since I already have the arrays I was hoping there is a way of consolidating them.  The examples I have found are hard to implement in the program I am working with.

Comment: This works great for use in code, but falls flat when you are going to let the user select the resulting units, like the question does.

Comment: You shouldn't use `decimal` for physical quantities, you should use `double`.

Answer (score 1):

When working in C# I like to use objects (when in Rome, right?).

Here's my "quick and dirty" take on solving the problem with objects. As @zzxyz mentioned, for each unit group we define a standard unit and calculate everything relative to that.

The huge advantage to this approach is that we define each unit once rather than making a big cross-reference table for all the possible combinations. And adding a new unit is easy - just define it.

Also, there's no need to hardcode a function for each call... just set the parameters of the Convert method call:

`weight.Convert(400, "kg", "g");`

As far as the objects go, I thought about giving Units both name and abbreviation properties, but for the sake of speed I kept only Name. But when populating it I used abbreviations.

The Output:

[image]

To run it:

`var app = new App_Conversion();
app.Run();`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    public class App_Conversion
    {
        public void Run()
        {
            var weight = getWeightUnitGroup();

            var w = weight.Convert("g", "kg");
            Console.WriteLine(w.ToString());

            var x = weight.Convert(400, "kg", "g");
            Console.WriteLine(x.ToString());

            var y = weight.Convert(12, "lb", "g");
            Console.WriteLine(y.ToString());

            var z = weight.Convert(7, "g", "lb");
            Console.WriteLine(z.ToString());
        }   

        private UnitGroup getWeightUnitGroup() 
        // we could also get the data from wherever and deserialize into these classes       
        {
            //base unit for the weight Unit Group
            var gram = new Unit("g", 1);

            var weight = new UnitGroup("Weight", UnitGroup.eType.Mass, gram);

            weight.AddUnit(new Unit("kg", 1000m));
            weight.AddUnit(new Unit("mg", 0.001m));
            weight.AddUnit(new Unit("oz", 28.35m));
            weight.AddUnit(new Unit("lb", 453.59m));

            return weight;
        }
    }

    public class UnitGroup
    {
        public enum eType
        {
            Mass = 1,
            Distance = 2
        }

        public eType Type { get; private set; }

        public string Name { get; private set; }

        public Unit BaseUnit { get; private set; }

        public List<Unit> Units { get; private set; } = new List<Unit>();

        public UnitGroup(string name, eType type, Unit baseUnit)
        {
            Name = name;
            Type = type;
            BaseUnit = baseUnit;
            AddUnit(baseUnit);
        }

        public void AddUnit(Unit unit)
        {
            Units.Add(unit);
            unit.AddToGroup(this);
        }

        public ConversionResult Convert(string fromName, string toName)
        {
            return Convert(1, fromName, toName);
        }

        public ConversionResult Convert(decimal qty, string fromName, string toName)
        {
            var from = Units.Where(u => u.Name.Equals(fromName)).First();

            var to = Units.Where(u => u.Name.Equals(toName)).First();

            var result = Decimal.Round(qty * (from.Quantity * to.ConvertToFactor),5);

            var formattedResult = $"{qty} {fromName} = {result} {toName}";

            return new ConversionResult(result, formattedResult);
        }
    }

    public class Unit
    {        
        public UnitGroup Group { get; private set; }

        public string Name { get; private set; }        

        public decimal Quantity { get; private set; }

        public decimal ConvertToFactor
        {
            get
            {
                return Group.BaseUnit.Quantity / Quantity;
            }
        }

        public Unit(string name, decimal qty)
        {
            Name = name;
            Quantity = qty;
        }

        public void AddToGroup(UnitGroup group)
        {
            Group = group;
        }
    }

    public class ConversionResult
    {
        private string formattedResult;

        public decimal Result { get; private set; }

        public ConversionResult(decimal result, string formattedResult)
        {
            Result = result;
            this.formattedResult = formattedResult;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return formattedResult;
        }
    }
}
```